# Is it recommended to use firebase database only for auto-update functionality

Tags: android, mysql, sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android application, which stores data in the MySQL database. This MySQL database is being updated using a SQL database in the cloud server. Only data in the cloud database is updated to the MySQL database and it is not updating vice versa. I'm planning to implement firebase database instead of MySQL only because of its auto-update and offline functionalities. Real-time database is not actually needed in my case, as the cloud data is not changing frequently(changes only in 1-2 days). Please help me to choose between firebase and MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is not real-time you may as well stick with your current solution. Firebase works really well for simple lists of constantly updating, live data. SQL works much better for highly relational data that may need complex querying.

It all comes down to the type of data in your app.

Comment: Then i will stick on to the method with SQL. Thanks